# spring boot config logging.pattern could not print log？

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

https://github.com/Dreampie/cloud-config-repo/blob/master/application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
  pattern:
    file: ${spring.application.name}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

When I use spring boot logging in spring cloud+docker，I could not found  any logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get a log file by default (this is a pure Spring Boot feature). You have to configure one (e.g. set `logging.file`). It looks like that's actually what you are trying to do but you have the wrong key in your config file (there's a `pattern` in yours).

Comment: I read this doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration

Comment: Read it again, and see if it tells you what the name of the config key is for a log file location.

Comment: yes,I had thought it was wrong to use to customize the file name，I only want to change filename end with date.